# Is there a file extension to file description script available for PHP?

Tags: php, file-extension

What I'm looking for is something which will take any file extension given to it and return a description of that extension.

For example :

```
$extension = 'PNG';
$description = ext_description($extension);

echo $description // Outputs 'Portable Network Graphic'
```

OR

```
 $extension = 'DOC';
 $description = ext_description($extension);

 echo $description // Outputs 'Microsoft Office Word Document'
```

I've searched google and nothing came up. It would be a huge time saver if anyone knew if such a script existed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, one is the [getID3 Library and there is the PHP build in fileinfo library](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/getid3-library/).

As the description for everybody is something else, you can create a simple look-up function that works on array data. You only need to add your file-types into the array and you're done:

```
function ext_description($extension) {
    static extensions = array(
        'png' => 'Portable Network Graphic',
        'doc' => 'Microsoft Office Word Document'
    );
    $extension = strtolower($extension);
    return isset($extensions[$extension])
        ? $extensions[$extension]
        : sprintf('Unknown File (%s)', $extension)
        ;
}
```

Comment: I was looking at that alright, however, I found it only returns the mime_type as opposed to description of the file extension. For example it will return 'image/gif' for a gif image, but not 'Graphic Interchange Format'

Comment: Here is a list of many known mime-types: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type but the description vary, so you could build that on your own needs, will add some little code.

Answer (score 2):

It does'nt exist but you can create one.

```
function ext_description($extension) {
    switch ($extension) {
    case "png":
        return "Portable Network Graphic";
    case "doc":
        return "Microsoft Office Word Document";
    default:
        return "Unknow extention";
}
```

You can find here a complete list of all existing extensions : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats_(alphabetical)

Comment: I think this might be what I have to do. I'll post a link to the code here when I'm finished for anyone who is looking for this too

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no easy way to do this in PHP.  The closest alternative would be the MIME type which you can get using `finfo` or `mime_content_type`.

If you are running on windows you could also use the `SHGetFileInfo` function which does exactly what you're looking for.

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762179(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am currently using for the above question if anyone else ever needs it.

```
/**
 * Takes a file extension and returns a readable file type.
 * 
 * @param string $ext
 * @return string
 * @example .doc returns Microsoft Word Document
 */
function file_extension_2_type($ext) {

    $files = json_decode('{".doc":"Microsoft Word Document",".docx":"Microsoft Word Open XML Document",".log":"Log File",".msg":"Outlook Mail Message",".pages":"Pages Document",".rtf":"Rich Text Format File",".txt":"Plain Text File",".wpd":"WordPerfect Document",".wps":"Microsoft Works Word Processor Document",".csv":"Comma Separated Values File",".dat":"Data File",".efx":"eFax Document",".gbr":"Gerber File",".key":"Keynote Presentation",".pps":"PowerPoint Slide Show",".ppt":"PowerPoint Presentation",".pptx":"PowerPoint Open XML Presentation",".sdf":"Standard Data File",".vcf":"vCard File",".xml":"XML File",".aif":"Audio Interchange File Format",".iff":"Interchange File Format",".m3u":"Media Playlist File",".m4a":"MPEG-4 Audio File",".mid":"MIDI File",".mp3":"MP3 Audio File",".mpa":"MPEG-2 Audio File",".wav":"WAVE Audio File",".wma":"Windows Media Audio File",".3g2":"3GPP2 Multimedia File",".3gp":"3GPP Multimedia File",".asf":"Advanced Systems Format File",".asx":"Microsoft ASF Redirector File",".avi":"Audio Video Interleave File",".flv":"Flash Video File",".mov":"Apple QuickTime Movie",".mp4":"MPEG-4 Video File",".mpg":"MPEG Video File",".swf":"Shockwave Flash Movie",".vob":"DVD Video Object File",".wmv":"Windows Media Video File",".3dm":"Rhino 3D Model",".max":"3ds Max Scene File",".bmp":"Bitmap Image File",".gif":"Graphical Interchange Format File",".jpg":"JPEG Image File",".png":"Portable Network Graphic",".psd":"Adobe Photoshop Document",".pspimage":"PaintShop Pro Image",".thm":"Thumbnail Image File",".tif":"Tagged Image File",".yuv":"YUV Encoded Image File",".ai":"Adobe Illustrator File",".drw":"Drawing File",".eps":"Encapsulated PostScript File",".ps":"PostScript File",".svg":"Scalable Vector Graphics File",".indd":"Adobe InDesign Document",".pct":"Picture File",".pdf":"Portable Document Format File",".qxd":"QuarkXPress Document",".qxp":"QuarkXPress Project File",".rels":"Open Office XML Relationships File",".xlr":"Works Spreadsheet",".xls":"Excel Spreadsheet",".xlsx":"Microsoft Excel Open XML Spreadsheet",".accdb":"Access 2007 Database File",".db":"Database File",".dbf":"Database File",".mdb":"Microsoft Access Database",".pdb":"Program Database",".sql":"Structured Query Language Data",".app":"Mac OS X Application",".bat":"DOS Batch File",".cgi":"Common Gateway Interface Script",".com":"DOS Command File",".exe":"Windows Executable File",".gadget":"Windows Gadget",".jar":"Java Archive File",".pif":"Program Information File",".vb":"VBScript File",".wsf":"Windows Script File",".gam":"Saved Game File",".nes":"Nintendo (NES) ROM File",".rom":"N64 Game ROM File",".sav":"Saved Game",".dwg":"AutoCAD Drawing Database File",".dxf":"Drawing Exchange Format File",".gpx":"GPS Exchange File",".kml":"Keyhole Markup Language File",".asp":"Active Server Page",".cer":"Internet Security Certificate",".csr":"Certificate Signing Request File",".css":"Cascading Style Sheet",".htm":"Hypertext Markup Language File",".html":"Hypertext Markup Language File",".js":"JavaScript File",".jsp":"Java Server Page",".php":"Hypertext Preprocessor File",".rss":"Rich Site Summary",".xhtml":"Extensible Hypertext Markup Language File",".8bi":"Photoshop Plug-in",".plugin":"Mac OS X Plug-in",".xll":"Excel Add-In File",".fnt":"Windows Font File",".fon":"Generic Font File",".otf":"OpenType Font",".ttf":"TrueType Font",".cab":"Windows Cabinet File",".cpl":"Windows Control Panel Item",".cur":"Windows Cursor",".dll":"Dynamic Link Library",".dmp":"Windows Memory Dump",".drv":"Device Driver",".lnk":"File Shortcut",".sys":"Windows System File",".cfg":"Configuration File",".ini":"Windows Initialization File",".keychain":"Mac OS X Keychain File",".prf":"Outlook Profile File",".bin":"Macbinary Encoded File",".hqx":"BinHex 4.0 Encoded File",".mim":"Multi-Purpose Internet Mail Message File",".uue":"Uuencoded File",".7z":"7-Zip Compressed File",".deb":"Debian Software Package",".gz":"Gnu Zipped Archive",".pkg":"Mac OS X Installer Package",".rar":"WinRAR Compressed Archive",".rpm":"Red Hat Package Manager File",".sit":"Stuffit Archive",".sitx":"Stuffit X Archive",".tar.gz":"Tarball File",".zip":"Zipped File",".zipx":"Extended Zip File",".dmg":"Mac OS X Disk Image",".iso":"Disc Image File",".toast":"Toast Disc Image",".vcd":"Virtual CD",".c":"C\/C++ Source Code File",".class":"Java Class File",".cpp":"C++ Source Code File",".cs":"Visual C# Source Code File",".dtd":"Document Type Definition File",".fla":"Adobe Flash Animation",".java":"Java Source Code File",".m":"Objective-C Implementation File",".pl":"Perl Script",".py":"Python Script",".bak":"Backup File",".gho":"Norton Ghost Backup File",".ori":"Original File",".tmp":"Temporary File",".dbx":"Outlook Express E-mail Folder",".msi":"Windows Installer Package",".part":"Partially Downloaded File",".torrent":"BitTorrent File"}', true);


    if (isset($files['.' . strtolower($ext)]))
        return $files['.' . strtolower($ext)] . ' (' . strtoupper($ext) . ')';


    return strtoupper($ext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use mime types of the file http://www.feedforall.com/mime-types.htm